Add date at the beginning of every line in my dataset in JCL
I would like to achieve the following thing.
I need to add the date in the following format (YYYYMMDD) to my dataset (length is 300 bytes) at the beginning of every line.
Therefore, I already have implemented this:
//STEP01 EXEC SORTDYN
//SYSIN DD *
    OPTION COPY
    OUTREC BUILD=(001:CYMD,10:001,290)
/*
//SORTIN   DD  DSN=FILE.TEST.WORK.SOME.FA,
//             DISP=SHR
//SORTOUT  DD  DSN=FILE.TEST.OUT.SOME.FA,
//             DISP=(MOD,CATLG),
//             SPACE=(CYL,(90,60),RLSE),VOL=(,,,9),
//             RECFM=FB,LRECL=300

However, it always points me to an error at this spot:
OUTREC BUILD=(001:CYMD,10:001,290)
                   $

My DFSORT is of version V2R4.
Thanks for any help.

I am answering my own question :)
I solved it by rewriting it that way:
//STEP035 EXEC SORTDYN
//SYSIN DD *
SORT FIELDS=COPY
OUTREC FIELDS=(1:DATE1,X,01,300)
/*
//SORTIN DD DSN=FILE.TEST.WORK.SOME.FA,
// DISP=SHR
//SORTOUT DD DSN=FILE.TEST.OUT.SOME.FA,
// DISP=(MOD,CATLG),
// SPACE=(CYL,(90,60),RLSE),VOL=(,,,9),
// RECFM=FB,LRECL=300

The entry OUTREC FIELDS=(1:DATE1,X,01,300) does the job.

Does this add the date to the start of every record? Your question as stated ("add the date to the dataset at the beginning") implies you want to insert the date as a new first record.

You are absolutely right. I was not absolutely clearly with my question. I wanted to add the current date at the beginning of every line in my dataset.
